# "Durant" at the end of a sentence?

Tags: vocabulaire

On an insert that came with my thermos, one part of the English side says:

> Keeps tea hot for up to 6 hours.

and the French side says:

> Garde le thé chaud jusqu'à 6 heures durant.

I'm unsure what the word "durant" does. Would the sentence have a different meaning (or be ungrammatical) if the word "durant" was removed from the sentence?

Comment: Best translated "for (durant) up to (jusqu'à) six hours". Why it can move to the end is an interesting question... I suppose you could replace it with English "in duration" for a similar syntax.

Comment: Good question. Recently I've wondered the same thing. Pity no one seems to have an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the meaning would be different, or at least ambiguous:

> *...jusqu'à six heures:*  **until** six o'clock.

> *...jusqu'à six heures **durant**:* **for** up to six hours.

As commented, it wouldn't make sense for a thermos documentation to specify a precise hour of the day until when tea is kept warm inside it so the meaning of the sentence without *durant* would be understood exactly like the longer one.

A different context might make distinct meanings more likely :

> *Il a dormi jusqu'à dix heures.* He slept until 10 o'clock.

> *Il à dormi jusqu'à dix heures durant.* He slept for up to 10 hours (in a row).

Note that the English ***during*** evolved from the French ***durant***, keeping the same meaning.

***Durant*** is formal in French so we usually prefer ***pendant*** but the latter can't be postfixed :

> Durant six heures. ✓
> Pendant six heures. ✓
> Six heures durant. ✓
> <s>Six heures pendant.</s> ✗

Comment: That's the right answer but I'd note that "jusqu'à [duration] durant" _feels_ a bit wrong. At least to my native ear. I'd have expect "garde le thé chaud 6 heures durant" or "garde le thé chaud jusqu'à 6 heures" (even if the second one could be ambiguous, cause seriously, who would be confused?).

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, the ambiguity is more theoretical than real here. An issue is we usually avoid to write *Garde le thé chaud jusqu'à pendant six heures* although it is common in spoken French. A solution can be *Garde le thé chaud pour une durée allant jusqu'à six heures*, but it's a little verbose.

Comment: "close to" as in "is a literal translation"

Comment: On the side of a thermos there is no ambiguity as the label can never mean "until 6 o'clock", however